# How to set content type to 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' in PHP while SOAP request

Tags: php, curl, soap, xmlhttprequest, soap-client

When I try to send a request to the WSDL I got this error Cannot process the message because the content type `text/xml; charset=utf-8` was not the expected type `application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8`

Here is my code

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?singleWsdl");
 $parameter = array(
    'User ID' => '0123',
    'Password' => 'mf@abc',
    'Pass Key' => 'abcdef1234',     
 );
$result = $client->getPassword($parameter);
```

I tried passing content type like this

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?wsdl",array('content type'=>'application/soap+xml'));
```

but didnot work.

Here is the WSDL Link :[WSDL Source Link](http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc)

Please share some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the SOAP version in your request to 1.2

```
  $client = new SoapClient("http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?wsdl",array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```